# Google compute not accessable

Tags: wordpress, google-compute-engine

I'm using Google compute cloud to build website for my clients after i setup the website it is not accessible from some countries such as IRAN ( I mean the site it self like example.com not the Google cloud control panel ) 
It simple says connection time out. I'm using instances for all the region's which are US,Europe, and Asia .
How can I access to these site from all around the world ?

Answer (score 2):

Due to export restrictions Google restricts access to and from some countries, including Iran.

Google restricts access to some of its business services in certain countries or regions, such as China, Crimea, Cuba, Iran, North Korea, Sudan, and Syria. Check following link for description.

[Countries or regions with restricted access](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2891389?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks for your answer I'm signed in from Malaysia and I don't have any issue but my website is on Google instance and the website I created is  not accessible, is it also for this restriction or I can set some setting to avoid it ?

Comment: @Arian,No,While you use API that time you need to follow rule of API provider

Comment: Thanks , that's very said